# MySQL stored procedure to insert or update table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EMPLOYEE_ID bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EMPLOYEE_NO VARCHAR(30),
EMPLOYEE_TYPE VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EMP_DETAIL(
EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL , 
INS_ID VARCHAR(20) , 
SALARY int,
PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID ,INS_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID)
);
```

I want to insert a value in the emp table and the emp_detail table. If the employee already exists, then only insert a record in the emp_details table.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERTEMP(
IN EMPLOYEE_NO VARCHAR(30),
IN EMPLOYEE_TYPE VARCHAR(20),
IN INS_ID VARCHAR(20),
IN SALARY INT
)
BEGIN 
DECLARE EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT;
   SET @EMPLOYEE_ID= (SELECT IFNULL((SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO=EMPLOYEE_NO AND EMPLOYEE_TYPE=EMPLOYEE_TYPE) ,'0'));
   IF @EMPLOYEE_ID=0 THEN
   INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NO ,EMPLOYEE_TYPE ) VALUES (EMPLOYEE_NO,EMPLOYEE_TYPE);
   SET @EMPLOYEE_ID=(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
   END IF;
   INSERT INTO EMP_DETAIL(EMPLOYEE_ID,INS_ID,SALARY) VALUES (@EMPLOYEE_ID,INS_ID,SALARY);
END
```

If I call the procedure:

```
CALL INSERTEMP(100, 'PERM','AAA',100);
```

first execute it created id as 1 in emp table if execute it in second time also insert with new id and third time it fails.

Can someone help?

Comment: You might want to consider not even using a stored procedure for such a simple SQL statement. Store procedures are not really a best practice anymore, just something you might want to read some articles on.

Comment: For the issue you are having, the call to inserttemp is probably not failing every third time, you should test some more occurrences of inserttemp

Comment: call to procedure is not failing , in first and second call it insert two rows auto generated column id is 1,2 in third call select query return two rows that failing .SET @EMPLOYEE_ID= (SELECT IFNULL((SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_NO=EMPLOYEE_NO AND EMPLOYEE_TYPE=EMPLOYEE_TYPE) ,'0'))

Comment: There you go, you figured it out, you can't SET a @EMPLOYEE_ID with a query that returns more than one row, you will have to select top 1

Comment: Thanks Brian I was able to fix that with other approach